# Exit with grace from DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, http-post, httpclient

How to we exit from HttpClient? There is no method found.

```
HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String userpass = usr + ":" + pwd;

HttpPost httpGet = new HttpPost(dataimport_cmd);
String encoding = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes("UTF-8"));
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

Client.execute(httpGet);
```

I tried enclosing the execute to a closeablehttpresponse but it didn't exit from the class.

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = (CloseableHttpResponse) 
Client.execute(httpGet);
response.close();
```

I've tried using return also to exit from the class.

return;

Comment: Why are you using a deprecated class? You won't find much help for deprecated issues

Comment: hmmmm. normally the IDE i'm using will indicated it. let me check the newer class

Answer (score 0):

If your http-client version is higher than 4.3, you can use CloseableHttpClient instead of HttpClient. It has a close() method.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
...
client.close();
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I went with this approach but it is still not exiting. Although I didn't used defaulthttpclient because the previous comment suggested not to use depracated class. CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
 HttpPost httpGet = new HttpPost(dataimport_cmd);
 String encoding = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes("UTF-8"));
 httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
     
 client.execute(httpGet); 
 client.close();

Comment: Actually your source code is correct and working for me. But if I use a url like "http://192.168.3.66:80", where 192.168.3.66 is down, then application is waiting on client.execute() call until timeout. You may have a similar situation.